# sql - multiple table select last value name

Tags: sql, mariadb, zabbix, groupwise-maximum

i have five table in a mariadb database, i want to select last value of each name table,

[image]

i do this sql command to have host, name and severity,

i tried this sql command :

```
select host, e.name, e.severity
from hosts
left join items i on (i.hostid = hosts.hostid)
inner join functions f on (f.itemid = i.itemid)
inner join triggers t on (t.triggerid = f.triggerid)
INNER JOIN events e ON (e.objectid = t.triggerid)
group by hosts.hostid;
```

i want last host, name and severity, 
i want this result in sql  :

[image]

Comment: I strongly suggest you NOT to use direct SQL queries on Zabbix, use APIs instead (https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.4/manual/api)

Comment: Define "last"..

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this with the supposition that triggerid is incremental in the triggers table

```
select host, e.name, e.severity
from hosts
left join items i on (i.hostid = hosts.hostid)
inner join functions f on (f.itemid = i.itemid)
inner join triggers t on (t.triggerid = f.triggerid)
INNER JOIN events e ON (e.objectid = t.triggerid)
where t.triggerid = (select max(t.triggerid) from triggers)
```

Comment: your request is very long and don't have result @zip

Comment: i don't know why query is very long